# “Asking price” vs. “Asked price”

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs, adjectives, phrases

Why is the phrase “asking price” instead of “asked price”?

Asking price: is the amount of money asked by a seller, so why isn’t "asked price” instead of “asking price” because the price is asked not asking.

To goes like:

> - what is the asked price for this product?

instead of

> - what is the asking price for this product?

Comment: You're right, the price is not asking...but the seller is asking.  To say that it was an *asked* price makes it sound like the seller was doing it in the past.

Comment: A price is a price unless the market in which the pricing occurs has fluctuating prices, as opposed to a price that does not change. Financial products and real estate, for example.

Answer (score 5):

**"Asked price"** would mean that the act of offering the product for a given price is already in the past.

On the contrary, **"asking price"** is an ongoing process, which isn't finished until you accept or deny the offer.

Comment: No one says price asked unless it's in a sentence like: The price asked was not the price received.  Asking price is only for prices in markets with fluctuating prices.

Answer (score 1):

- Asking price is often used on stock and other financial products' markets:

The asking price and the selling price of a security (stock, bonds, private shares, etc.). There is a parallel there.

Thus, **"asking" is used in markets for products where prices are not "set" but can move up and down**.

So, in real estate, a house might have an **asking price** because two weeks from now, if it doesn't sell, the seller might lower the price. Also, when a potential buyer offers to buy a house, they offer a price they are willing to pay. In other words, my asking price is not necessarily the price I will get. It's often a negotiation with a buyer.

Financial markets, as mentioned for stocks etc, above. typically use asking price for trading and financial products whose prices move up and down in a market over a period of time and can be graphed. It means the price is not set  in stone. It depends on the market

For other types of products, where prices do not fluctuate, they are just prices, or retail or wholesale prices. But those are in effect stable in a market. They do not fluctuate at the whim of a market of buyer and sellers even though a manufacturer may decide to raise or lower a price for a product.

Answer (score 0):

'What is you asking price?', is the interrogative of the present continuous verb tense. The present continuous is the verb tense that is usually used when you are talking about something that is happening at the point of time during which you are speaking, and which has not yet been concluded.

> Q. What are you doing?
>
> A. I am leaving the house.
>
> A. I am working on the quotation for the new development.
>
> A. I am playing the drums.

The present continuous, with an added time parameter, may also be used if you want to talk about a time in the near future instead of at the instant during that you are speaking, e.g.:

> Q. What are you doing tonight?
>
> A. I am going to a friend's place.
>
> Q. Where are you going on holiday next week?
>
> A. I am going to Paris for a week, then I will be going to Rome for a
>   few days.